# RxJS + Node.js Http Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest, reactive-programming, rxjs

Nodejs server side implementation: How to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/request with https://www.npmjs.com/package/rx to make GET request to https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript.json?

Goal: I attempting to accomplish constant streaming whenever there are data changes to whatever site api url I'm using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you will be unable to receive updates when `https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript.json` is updated as there is no way for them to push this information to the client.

Services such as Github will let you register a `webhook` which will let them push data to an endpoint on your server. I am unsure if Reddit supports this.

As an alternate solution, and building on what AkkarinZA said in his answer, you could poll the json document using something similar to the following:

```
var fetchContent = function(url) {
    return rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
        request(url, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) { observer.onError(); }
            else { observer.onNext({response: response, body: body }); }
            observer.onCompleted();
        })
    });
};

rx.Observable.interval(1000)
    .map(function() { return 'https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript.json' })
    .flatMap(fetchContent)
    .map(/* do something */)
    .subscribe();
```

Polling such as this isn't a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create an observable with observers notified from the callback. Try something like:

```
rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
  request('https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript.json', function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) { observer.onError(); }
    else { observer.onNext({response: response, body: body }); }
    observer.onCompleted();
  })
})
.map(/* do something */)
.subscribe();
```

Comment: By my understanding, Jek is wanting a new observable to be omitted when the Json is updated.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't get that from his question on the first couple of reads.